# How to add AOV post hoc test to ggplot2 boxplot? I can't plot the labels on my graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I wonder what's wrong to my code?
My code is like:

```
a=aov(tem.range~Butterfly.colonies, data=my.data)
summary(a)
tHSD <- TukeyHSD(a, ordered = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95)
tHSD
generate_label_df <- function(HSD, flev){
  # Extract labels and factor levels from Tukey post-hoc
  Tukey.levels <- HSD[[flev]][,4]
  Tukey.labels <- multcompLetters(Tukey.levels)['Letters']
  plot.labels <- names(Tukey.labels[['Letters']])
  boxplot.df <- ddply(my.data, flev, function (x) max(fivenum(x$y)) + 0.2)

  plot.levels <- data.frame(plot.labels, labels = Tukey.labels[['Letters']], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  # Merge it with the labels
  labels.df <- merge(plot.levels, boxplot.df, by.x = 'plot.labels', by.y = flev, sort = FALSE)
  return(labels.df)
}
ggplot(my.data, aes(x=Butterfly.colonies, y=tem.range))+
 geom_boxplot(width = 0.5) +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, by = 2))+
 theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,3,1,3),"cm"))+
 labs(y="tem.range(Celsius")+
 labs(x="Colony")+
 geom_text(data = generate_label_df(tHSD, 'Butterfly.colonies'), 
    aes(x =  plot.labels, y = V1, label = labels))
```

However, in the end there was an error

And thus, I can't put the label on my graph
[image]

I hope it will be like:
[image]

Comment: welcome to SO, could you post a version that uses R's built in data...maybe use `data(iris)` and `aes(Species, Sepal.Length)` to approximate your test case. Or you could just add `my.data` as table text, so that people can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

my code:

```
a=aov(tem.range~Butterfly.colonies,data=my.data)
tHSD <- TukeyHSD(a, ordered = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95)
generate_label_df <- function(HSD, flev){
Tukey.levels <- HSD[[flev]][,4]
Tukey.labels <- multcompLetters(Tukey.levels)['Letters']
plot.labels <- names(Tukey.labels[['Letters']])
boxplot.df <- ddply(my.data, flev, function (x) max(fivenum(x$y)) + 0.2)
plot.levels <- data.frame(plot.labels, labels = Tukey.labels[['Letters']],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
labels.df <- merge(plot.levels, boxplot.df, by.x = 'plot.labels', by.y = flev, sort = FALSE)
return(labels.df)}
ggplot(my.data, aes(x=Butterfly.colonies, y=tem.range))+geom_boxplot(width = 0.5) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, by = 2))+ theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,3,1,3),"cm"))+labs(y="tem.range(Celsius")+labs(x="Colony")+geom_text(data = generate_label_df(tHSD, 'Butterfly.colonies'), aes(x = plot.labels, y = V1, label = labels))
```